# How can I show the GLSL code generate by node?

Tags: game-engine, node-editor, shaders, opengl

Sorry for my english.

how can i show the code generate by the node and can i write my own node Element?
Can i add a uniform float var? in order to comunicate with the fragment shaders?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to insert your own data into a node shader is to use vertex or object color (max of 3 floats each = 6 floats). Other than that you can either:

- Use an image as an input, using a specific UV
  lookup, and then using python to set a pixels colour.
- use your own GLSL shader (which means you have to do all the lighting
  yourself, and real time shadows become hard),
- create your own node (which involves recompiling blender itself).

I wish there were a better way than the three above, but if there are, I am unaware of them.

Answer (score 0):

I find a solution to export the material to GLSL and to it.

First install the plugin [export to glsl](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Game_Engine/Export_GLSL).
Export the material.
Modify the fragment shader or vertex.
For example change const to uniform, and charge the shaders.